# NPM install fails with NVM and Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nvm

I am using NVM to install Node.js 16.15.0 inside a Docker container.

I get an error when running `npm ci`:

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! /atomix/node_modules/npm-conf/lib/conf.js:169
npm ERR!            throw err;
npm ERR!            ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0'
npm ERR!     at Object.statSync (fs.js:898:3)
npm ERR!     at Conf.loadUser (/atomix/node_modules/npm-conf/lib/conf.js:162:21)
npm ERR!     at module.exports (/atomix/node_modules/npm-conf/index.js:32:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/atomix/node_modules/get-proxy/index.js:2:36)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18) {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   syscall: 'stat',
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0'
npm ERR! }
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM trzeci/emscripten
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
RUN apt update \
  && apt install libglew-dev -y \
  && wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash \
  && apt install htop \
    && apt install procps -y

ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.15.0

RUN chmod +x $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
RUN . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /atomix

RUN npm i flow-typed -g

# NPM 7+ automatically installs peer deps so disable this as it fails our install
RUN npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

These installation instructions for NVM are copied from NVM itself.

When I roll it back from 16.15.0 to 10.16.0 (which I know works) it works successfully. Why does the newer version of Node.js fail?

Comment: Any reason you're using `nvm` in a container and not simply starting with a node [16.15 image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/16.15/images/sha256-a1f665affa21f2b46e476e0cb77d92b83e3713355bd28d026c257b16353c6d90?context=explore)?

Comment: @Phil Good comment. We use Docker for development and wanted to switch Node versions easily without rebuilding the whole container. Probably not worth the extra complexity though. But right now I dont want to rewrite my whole Dockerfile especially since all I've done is change the Node version

Comment: For a couple of reasons, version managers like `nvm` don't work especially well in Docker and aren't usually necessary (you could build your image `FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}` if you did need to build images against multiple Node versions).  I'd also recommend starting from the `node` base image, or else directly installing Node by downloading it and unpacking it without `nvm` involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the official Node.JS Docker images for whatever part you need Node for. You can use a build arg to specify the version.

Use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to create whatever assets you need for the Node stage.

```docker
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.5

# Build stage
FROM emscripten/emsdk AS emcc
WORKDIR /build
COPY your-src-files/ ./
RUN emcc ...

# Run
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}

WORKDIR /atomix
RUN npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
RUN npm i flow-typed -g

COPY --from=emcc /build/your-compiled-files ./
RUN ...
```

To change the Node version, you simply build the image with a `NODE_VERSION` build arg...

```sh
docker build --build-arg NODE_VERSION=17 .
```